# Sifr3 - Is it possible to override CSS styling with parent selector?

Tags: css, sifr

I would like to override setting that already defined with selecting
parent selector but I don't know how.
Say, there are 2 pages on a website like the following...

-Home page-
`<body><h1 class="sifr">Home</h1></body>`

-About page-
`<body class="about"><h1 class="sifr">About</h1></body>`

then, I have these in sirf-config.js...

sIFR.replace(fontname, {
 selector: 'h1.sifr',
 css: '.sIFR-root { color: #666666; font-size:29px; }'
});

sIFR.replace(fontname, {
 selector: 'body.about h1.sifr',
 css: '.sIFR-root { color: #FFFFFF; font-size:29px; }'
});

but it doesn't work...

If anybody help me I would appreciate.

Comment: Thanks for the answers but this is sifr-config.js specific question. I know how it's simple to do with just CSS but with sifr that;s not the case apparently. I'm still struggling to achieve this, please someone help! I probably should have tagged JavaScript as well..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the replacements for `body.about h1.sifr` *before* `h1.sifr`. sIFR doesn't calculate specificity but executes the replacements in-order. Replacing `h1.sifr` replaces all such elements, so `body.about h1.sifr` only finds elements that have already been replaced.

Comment: Thank you very much. You are star! I didn't know about this but now i like sifr more and more!

Answer (score 0):

Check the order your loading CSS vs issuing the replace commands ...

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Sifr, so I don't know exactly how it works. I assume that the code creates CSS code like this:

```
h1.sifr { color: #666666; font-size: 29px; }
body.about h1.sifr { color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 29px; }
```

If it does, that will override the color style for the heading in the about page, as the selector for the second line is more specific than the selector in the first line.

You can read more about specificity [here](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/advanced_conflict.htm).

If it doesn't work, it's because there is something in your code that doesn't look like you think it does, and it may very well be something in some other part of your code that you haven't shown here that is causing the problem.

You can use the Firebug plugin in Firefox to inspect the elements in the page to see exactly which css is affecting each element.